# Android - socket.io посыл данных всем клиентам в виде byte[]

Tags: java, android, socket.io

Здравствуйте.
Моя проблема в том, что я никак не соображу в чем **именно** может быть проблема.
Я использую это в качестве сервера https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio.

```
server.addEventListener("msg", byte[].class, (SocketIOClient client, byte[] data, AckRequest ackRequest) -> {
    server.getBroadcastOperations().sendEvent("msg", data);
});
```

Так вот такой код крашит приложение, **если подключены 2 и более клиентов**.

```
06-04 13:13:50.683 11602-12701/gcd.bint E/EventThread: Task threw exception
                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
                                                       at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Socket.toArray(Socket.java:447)
                                                       at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Socket.onevent(Socket.java:309)
                                                       at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Socket.onpacket(Socket.java:280)
                                                       at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Socket.access$100(Socket.java:28)
                                                       at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Socket$2.lambda$new$1(Socket.java:113)
                                                       at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Socket$2$$Lambda$2.call(Unknown Source)
                                                       at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
                                                       at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Manager.ondecoded(Manager.java:413)
                                                       at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Manager.access$1600(Manager.java:29)
                                                       at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Manager$7.call(Manager.java:389)
                                                       at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
                                                       at gcd.bint.network.socket.parser.Parser$Decoder.add(Parser.java:169)
                                                       at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Manager.ondata(Manager.java:409)
                                                       at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Manager.access$1100(Manager.java:29)
                                                       at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Manager$2.call(Manager.java:358)
                                                       at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
                                                       at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.onPacket(Socket.java:511)
                                                       at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.access$1000(Socket.java:31)
                                                       at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket$5.call(Socket.java:313)
                                                       at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
                                                       at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.onPacket(Transport.java:134)
                                                       at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.onData(Transport.java:130)
                                                       at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket.access$200(WebSocket.java:24)
                                                       at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket$2$3.run(WebSocket.java:112)
                                                       at io.socket.thread.EventThread$2.run(EventThread.java:80)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-04 13:13:50.688 11602-12701/gcd.bint E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: EventThread
                                                      Process: gcd.bint, PID: 11602
                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
                                                          at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Socket.toArray(Socket.java:447)
                                                          at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Socket.onevent(Socket.java:309)
                                                          at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Socket.onpacket(Socket.java:280)
                                                          at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Socket.access$100(Socket.java:28)
                                                          at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Socket$2.lambda$new$1(Socket.java:113)
                                                          at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Socket$2$$Lambda$2.call(Unknown Source)
                                                          at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
                                                          at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Manager.ondecoded(Manager.java:413)
                                                          at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Manager.access$1600(Manager.java:29)
                                                          at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Manager$7.call(Manager.java:389)
                                                          at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
                                                          at gcd.bint.network.socket.parser.Parser$Decoder.add(Parser.java:169)
                                                          at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Manager.ondata(Manager.java:409)
                                                          at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Manager.access$1100(Manager.java:29)
                                                          at gcd.bint.network.socket.client.Manager$2.call(Manager.java:358)
                                                          at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
                                                          at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.onPacket(Socket.java:511)
                                                          at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.access$1000(Socket.java:31)
                                                          at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket$5.call(Socket.java:313)
                                                          at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
                                                          at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.onPacket(Transport.java:134)
                                                          at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.onData(Transport.java:130)
                                                          at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket.access$200(WebSocket.java:24)
                                                          at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket$2$3.run(WebSocket.java:112)
                                                          at io.socket.thread.EventThread$2.run(EventThread.java:80)
                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)`
```

И сам блок(**io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3**):

```
private static Object[] toArray(JSONArray array) {
    int length = array.length();
    Object[] data = new Object[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Object v;
        try {
            v = array.get(i);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "An error occured while retrieving data from JSONArray", e);
            v = null;
        }
        data[i] = JSONObject.NULL.equals(v) ? null : v;
    }
    return data;
}
```

Если же подключен **только один клиент**, то все работает норм.

Слушаю если что так:

```
socket.on("msg", args -> {
    Log.d("bytes: " + Arrays.toString((byte[]) args[0]));
});
```

При ошибке результат: `bytes: []`

Я понимаю, что ключевое здесь `int org.json.JSONArray.length()`, но где начало цепочки?

Comment: Поппобуйте `foreach`

Comment: тоесть при прослушивании? или отправке?

Comment: Прошу прощения, а разве в исключении не написано что ошибка возникает при попытке узнать длину вашего Json-массива? >> int length = array.length();<< тут array точно не nullpointer?

Comment: ну я же написал, что не совсем чайник) --> тогда так: почему он(массив, при 2 и более клиентах) == null ? а если один клиент, он не null?

Comment: я пробовал проверять длинну массива (array != null) ? array.lenght : 0 , но это не вариант, так как данные то все-равно не получены

Comment: А каким образом происходит процесс регистрации/подключения клиентов? Это на вашей стороне, или библиотека всё берёт на себя?

Comment: + Ещё момент, внутри sendEvent есть такая строчка >>packet.setData(Arrays.asList(data));<< Надеюсь, в вашем массиве data нет null элементов? Аналогично, не известно куда будет возвращать ваш массив метод toArray, в котором так же есть null элементы (что потенциально опасно для коллекций), в яве часто встречаются библиотеки где вместо null надо слать пустые объекты, >>data[i] = JSONObject.NULL.equals(v) ? null : v;<< будет иметь вид примерно следующий: data[i] = JSONObject.NULL.equals(v) ? new Object() : v;
Но, это практически пальцм в небо...

Answer (score 0):

Как и было мне предложено, вариант с foreach:

```
server.addEventListener("msg", byte[].class, (SocketIOClient client, byte[] data, AckRequest ackRequest) -> {
    for(SocketIOClient socketIOClient:server.getAllClients()){
        socketIOClient.sendEvent("msg", data);
    }
    //server.getBroadcastOperations().sendEvent("msg", data);
});
```

Видимо в api netty просто пока еще этого не предусмотрели.
Будем пробовать...